# Fastest way to check elements of large array not present in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to check which of the elements of an array are not present in a MySQL table.
I was making individual queries but it was blowing up my MySQL.

Comment: Use a query with `NOT IN`.

Comment: How large?  You can use an ` NOT IN` clause

Comment: Alternatively create a table with the array as data and use an outer join to see what's missing. or a Not exists.

Comment: @Machavity, that's not a duplicate—it's the opposite question.

Comment: @BillKarwin Ah, so it is. Retracted it

Answer (score 4):

Several answers and comments on this thread misunderstand what the OP asked for. The OP didn't ask for the values in the MySQL table that are not present in your PHP array. The OP asked for the opposite: values in the PHP array that are not present in the MySQL table.

Load the values into a temporary table. I'm assuming a variable `$array` that contains integers. Here's code to insert many rows at once. If this would generate an INSERT statement longer than `max_allowed_packet` then  load the array in batches.

```
$pdo->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE values_to_search (value INT PRIMARY KEY)");

$sql = "INSERT INTO values_to_search (value) VALUES " 
    . implode(",", array_fill(1, count($array), "(?)"));
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($array);
```

Do an outer join to the table you're searching. Where there is no match, the value is not present.

```
$sql = "SELECT v.value
    FROM values_to_search AS v
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable t ON v.value = t.value
    WHERE t.value IS NULL";
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I use this solution and it works but it still takes 140 seconds just to do the outer join with 17000 lines. Is this normal?

Comment: You should have an index on the value column on which you are joining, but even without an index, I think 140 seconds is too long. You may have a problem on your server. For example, is it swapping? Get a system administrator to check it out.

Comment: I use a VPS with 3 cores and 4Gb ram, it compares 17k lines with 57k now it's taking 160 seconds.

Comment: What about the index?

Comment: I added index and now it takes more than 200 seconds. Only the temp table has index because the other is from prestashop and i  dindn't change it

Comment: Well you need an index on the table you're searching if you want to improve this. I can't make you do that, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a huge amount of values, load them into a temp table and Left join on that.

```
  $sql =  "select t.* from temptable t left join foo f on f.id = t.id where f.id is null";
```

Comment: If you're doing `VARCHAR` values you **need** to escape as well, you can't just concatenate.

Comment: @BillKarwin ooops!  thanks for the heads up, correcing the querey

Comment: @BillKarwin All updated to reflect OP desired result!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and `select distinct ...` to get the desired results quickly:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
$mysql_array = [];
// $mysql_array = [3,7,9]; // uncomment this if you wish to test without DB data

$sql = 'select distinct id as id from mysql_table';

// mysql querying functions or PDO or whatever

while(looping results)
{
    $mysql_array[] = $row['id'];
}

print_r(array_diff($array, $mysql_array));

// If using $mysql_array = [3,7,9]; test data then you will get this result
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [7] => 8
    [9] => 0
)
*/
```

---

**Important Note:**

The method outlined above has the potential of exhausting the available memory available to your PHP script if the `distinct` query returns a million records or more.

Comment: This is a bad idea, because it consumes an unbounded amount of memory in your PHP script depending on the number of distinct id's in the MySQL table. This could be billions.

Comment: @BillKarwin true, but OP did not specify the size of their table. I choose to leave this answer here because there's always more than one way of doing things. I'll make note of the memory issue that you pointed out though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an alternative solution, based on the fact that the OP's context implies that *all* the already registered values are to be explored.
*Edit: looking at @MonkeyZeus answer I realize they may be registered more than once, so I added `DISTINCT` to my query below.*

Might be faster since it uses only one simple query... but not sure since it also iterates a huge array.
In the other hand, it can't cause memory issues, since only `fetch()` is used, rather than `fetchAll()`.

Assuming `value` is the name of the involved column and `$searched_values` is the (simple) array containing the searched values:

```
// make known values and searched values sorted the same
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT DISTINCT value FROM mytable ORDER BY value');
sort($searched_values);

$unknown_values = [];
$known_value = NULL;

foreach ($searched_values as $searched_value) {
    if (!$known_value) {
        // previous known_value already consumed (or end), try to get next one 
        $known_value = $stmt->fetch()['value'];
    }
    if ($known_value == $searched_value) {
        // consume current known_value
        $known_value = NULL;
    } else {
        // otherwise current $searched_value is unknown, register it:
        $unknown[] = $searched_value;
    }
}
```